# PowerPoint Web Presentation to HQ Video

Tags: ffmpeg, powerpoint, video-processing

I am building a recording script for PowerPoint presentations on the web( during a web meeting). I am  looking to build a demuxer which will be easier to work with for the rest of the ffmpeg code as we query the timeline and return the current slide image and let ffmpeg handle the encoding of the frame in the output video.  I want output to be in MP4 so that it is of high quality.

So, the idea of demuxer is to convert the PPT which are variable bit rate into AVI/MPG at fixed CBR and then convert into MP4. What is best way to go about doing this or any other better solutions ? Any pointers to code in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, do you want to convert your PowerPoint presentation to HD video? I google "PowerPoint presentation to HD video converter", and get this [Wondershare PPT to Video converter](http://www.ppt-to-dvd.com#110) , maybe you could have a free try.

BTW, if you don't want to generated HD video,  you can use these free powerpoint to video converters:
http://masternewmedia.org/convert-powerpoint-to-video-guide-to-the-best-free-services